# Transform website so that it is like a mini version of desktop website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust my website to all mobile devices. What I mean by adjusting is that the website should look exactly like the desktop version, just in small. I tried it with transform but there doesnt to seem a good effect on it.

I try to do it like bs.to, where all content looks the same, as well on desktop as on mobile devices.

Lets just try it with the searchbar.

Html-Code

```css
.outercontainer {
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}


/*Navigation-Struktur*/

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 45px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.grid-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.grid-container>div {
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 18px;
  align-self: center;
}


/*Searchbar*/

.grid-item3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item1"> <strong style="font-size: 25px;">Deutschland</strong></div>
    <div class="grid-item2">
      Kategorie:
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item3"> <input type="text" placeholder="Suche deine Events..." style="width: 100%;font-size:17px;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item4"> <a href="#">Anmelden </a></div>
    <div class="grid-item5"> <a href="#"> Registrieren</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the width to 100% with a max-width:1200px but I need the code to adjust the size of the elements in the searchbar. How to do so: Adjusting elements to the actual screen size, so it is looking like the mini version of the desktop version

Comment: That's not how responsive design works.

Comment: Start here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Also see: [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [bootstrap responsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply *delete*  the following line from  the `<head>` section of your code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then the page will be zoomed down to whatever size the screen has.

However, this has nothing to do with responsive design and is considered rather unprofessional (and definitely not useful)...

Comment: I need to double click to zoom out. Thats not what I wanted. It should be zoomed out before a user gets on the page. Anyway too achieve that?

Comment: Thank you for yout help! I know its unprofessional but I just want it this way^^. Maybe I think in future avout responsive design :)